# COUNT Function in MS SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am using  a query as stored procedure but the COUNT function is not working i.e. its not counting the coulmns. It is only working fine when I group only three columns. But grouping more than three columns creating problem and the count column shows values separately... Not counting the figures... Help plzz

```
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].[getNoOfComplaints_SP] 
@Depart_ID INT, 
@City_ID INT, 
@Nature_ID INT, 
@Detail_ID INT, 
@Status_ID INT, 
@Category_ID INT, 
@Source_ID INT, 
@Gender_ID INT 

AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT Department_Info.Depart_Name, COUNT(Complaint_Info.Depart_ID) AS NumberOfComplaints 
FROM Complaint_Info 
LEFT JOIN Department_Info 
ON Complaint_Info.Depart_ID = Department_Info.Depart_ID 
GROUP BY 
Department_Info.Depart_Name, 
Complaint_Info.City_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Nature_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Detail_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Status_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Cat_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Source_ID, 
Complaint_Info.G_ID 
Having 
(@City_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.City_ID = @City_ID) 
AND
(@Nature_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Nature_ID = @Nature_ID) 
AND 
(@Detail_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Detail_ID = @Detail_ID) 
AND 
(@Status_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Status_ID = @Status_ID) 
AND
(@Category_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Cat_ID = @Category_ID) 
AND
(@Source_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Source_ID = @Source_ID) 
AND 
(@Gender_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.G_ID = @Gender_ID) 
END
```

Comment: Could you format the code please?

Comment: How-to guide for formatting: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: At any rate, the fields in your GROUP BY clause must be in your SELECT clause. You'll also need to change HAVING to WHERE.

Comment: I dont want the fields in my Group By clause in my SELECT clause

Answer (score 0):

COUNT function counts the rows in each group. If you add

```
Department_Info.Depart_Name,
Complaint_Info.City_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Nature_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Detail_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Status_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Cat_ID, 
Complaint_Info.Source_ID, 
Complaint_Info.G_ID
```

in the GROUP BY clause, COUNT function will return the number of entries that have same Depart_Name, City_ID, Nature_ID, Detail_ID, Status_ID, Cat_ID, Source_ID, G_ID.

So probably you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].[getNoOfComplaints_SP]
@Depart_ID INT,
@City_ID INT,
@Nature_ID INT,
@Detail_ID INT,
@Status_ID INT,
@Category_ID INT,
@Source_ID INT,
@Gender_ID INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT Department_Info.Depart_Name, COUNT(abc.Depart_ID) AS NumberOfComplaints FROM
(SELECT Complaint_Info.Depart_ID, COUNT(Complaint_Info.Depart_ID) AS NumberOfComplaints FROM Complaint_Info
GROUP BY Complaint_Info.Depart_ID, Complaint_Info.City_ID, Complaint_Info.Nature_ID, Complaint_Info.Detail_ID, Complaint_Info.Status_ID, Complaint_Info.Cat_ID, Complaint_Info.Source_ID, Complaint_Info.G_ID
Having
(@Depart_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Depart_ID = @Depart_ID)
AND
(@City_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.City_ID = @City_ID)
AND
(@Nature_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Nature_ID = @Nature_ID)
AND
(@Detail_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Detail_ID = @Detail_ID)
AND
(@Status_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Status_ID = @Status_ID)
AND
(@Category_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Cat_ID = @Category_ID)
AND
(@Source_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.Source_ID = @Source_ID)
AND
(@Gender_ID = -1 OR Complaint_Info.G_ID = @Gender_ID)) AS abc
JOIN Department_Info ON abc.Depart_ID = Department_Info.Depart_ID
Group By Department_Info.Depart_Name
END
```